# Overriding AWS auto scaling policy with Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I am working on aws autoscaling policy and is completely working fine with desired 2, max 3 and min 1 as count of instances.
I also have one lambda function which starts my ec2 instances at 9am and stop my ec2 instances at 6pm. This lambda function has applied on ec2 instances which is not a part of autoscaling configuration.
What I want this time, I want to apply lambda function on ec2 instances which we have launched using autoscaling. What is currently happening when I am applying lambda function to ec2 instances in autoscaling it stops those ec2 instances but with in a short moment it starts those instances (due to autoscaling config rules). So is there anyway by which i can override autoscaling policy?
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Disable the autoscaling if you want to manually manage it through lambda function.

Comment: okay thanks @Marcin. But is there any workaround by which we can control ec2 instances from lambda and autoscaling policies.

Comment: You can use lambda to generate some custom metric and setup autoscaling to follow your metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use scheduled scaling. It will scaleout on scale in resources based on cron expression you specify.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html
Or
Use python SDK (boto3) to handle autoscaling using lambda. you nad to attach iam  role to lambda which will allow lambda to access autoscaling group. create lambda function in python using boto3 library modify autoscaling policy.